# Classification model using xgboost package

Tags: classification, text-classification, multilabel-classification, xgboost

As a valid argument in xgboost model, I converted a character to a factor variable(eg. "A" "B" "C") and further to numeric factor variable(e.g "0" "1" "2"). Which function can I use to convert the numeric factors back to factor variable? I have to use it in a classification model.

Comment: i think you are looking for Label Encoder. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html